# Can't get simple assembly code to run on 3B+ board

Tags: pi-3b+, bare-metal

I am writing a bare metal code to run on GPIO 4 on raspberry pi 3B+

```
.section .init

.globl _start

_start:
    # pin 4 for 3B+
    ldr r0, =0x3F200000
    mov r1, #1
    lsl r1, #12
    str r1, [r0, #0] 
loop$:  
    #turn on the pin
    mov r1, #1
    lsl r1, #4
    str r1, [r0, #28]
    
    #delay
    mov r2, #0x3F000
    wait1$:
        sub r2, #1
        cmp r2, #0
        bne wait1$

    #turn off the pin 4
    mov r1, #1
    lsl r1, #4
    str r1,[r0,#40]
    
    #another delay
    mov r2, #0x3F000
    wait2$:
        sub r2, #1
        cmp r2, #0
        bne wait2$
    
    b loop$
```

My linker file content:

```
SECTIONS {
    .init 0x8000 : {
        *(.init)
    }
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(*)
    }
}
```

and my make file content:

```
default:
    arm-none-eabi-as start.s -o main.o
    arm-none-eabi-ld -T linker.ld main.o --no-undefined -o kernel.elf
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy kernel.elf -O binary kernel7.img
```

Then im replacing the kernel7.img on the SD card with mine (removing any other kernels of course). I really appreciate any help & thank you in advance.

Comment: Website https://forums.raspberrypi.com//viewforum.php?f=72 may be helpful.